# I want to send data from an api from one route to another in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-routes

I have a built an app using flutter that fetches information from an api and it displays it in a list tile. I would like to enable the ontap function so that whenever anyone taps on an item in the list tile it opens another page and displays that information
This is the list tile code

```
 itemCount: prospectList.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      final x = prospectList.data[i];
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(x.firstname),
                        subtitle: Text(x.lastname),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                          child: Text(x.firstname[0],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              )),
                        ),
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => CustomerInfo())),
                      );
```

I get this error

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CustomerInfo(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#5a50d]]):
The getter 'data' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: data

The relevant error-causing widget was
CustomerInfo
```

The api call

```
Future<String> _fetchData() async {
    setState(() => loading = true);

    final response = await http.get('run.mocky.io/v3/ad6092cd-3b2d-4b62-92f1-4198f697f3d3');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final datas = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final prospectListFromJson = ProspectList.fromJson(datas);

      setState(() {
        prospectList = prospectListFromJson;
        loading = false;
      });
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchData();
  }
```

Comment: Please share the code for `ProspectList`.

Comment: I have posted a link to ```ProspectList``` it is in services.dart class. I used json serialization and divided it into two classes. services.dart is the main class

Comment: Where do you retrieve the json file?

Comment: from https://run.mocky.io/v3/ad6092cd-3b2d-4b62-92f1-4198f697f3d3

Comment: Ok. Now, where are you calling the API and how are you passing it to the Widget where you want to show it.

Comment: I have added the api call

Comment: Can you print `prospectListFromJson` in the API call and check if it is proper or not...

Comment: this is the result ->  Instance of 'ProspectList'

Comment: Can you print `datas` and check what that is printing?

Comment: The _fetchData() is supposed to return a `String` but it returns nothing. However, I would like to see the entire code instead of what you have shared. As in, the entire WIdget.

Comment: I get this -> Instance of 'ProspectList'. But if I print response.body I get the whole json response

Comment: Link to the whole widget https://github.com/Kevnlan/flutter-list/blob/main/model/index.dart

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
Future<ProspectList> _fetchData() async {
  final response = await http.get('run.mocky.io/v3/ad6092cd-3b2d-4b62-92f1-4198f697f3d3');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var datas;
    datas = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final prospectListFromJson = ProspectList.fromJson(datas);
    return prospectListFromJson;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

FutureBuilder(
  future: _fetchData(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ProspectList> snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      prospectList = snapshot.data;
      if(prospectList != null){
        return List.separated...
      }
      else{
        // Show some error message...
      }
    }
    else if(snapshot.hasError){
      // Show some error message...
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
)
```

If you use FutureBuilder, you won't have to wonder if the data has been loaded or not.

Comment: Corrected the mistake.

Comment: I noticed it too

Comment: Cool. So, I hope it solves all your errors.